# How set interval() and clear interval() works under the hood

Tags: javascript, image, button, setinterval, clearinterval

this is what I have done so far. The function for click on other buttons is to have an array filtered from data array and provide back and forth buttons functionality. the specific part about which i want to know is this piece of code. and could it be done more efficiently? i am sure its wrong but can't point why clearnInterval() doesn't work and i get an error after 4 seconds even though the array is done iterating.

```
mainBtns.forEach(mainBtn => {
   mainBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
       mainBtn.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
       //homeBtn
       const setInt = null;
       if(mainBtn.dataset.name === 'home'){
           setInt = setInterval(() => {
               i++;
               targetTest.src = data[i].src;
               targetTest.alt = data[i].alt;
               console.log(targetTest);
               functionalBtns(data);
               if(i > length){
                   clearTimeout();
                   targetTest.src = data[0].src;
                   targetTest.alt = data[0].alt;
               }
           },4000);
       }
```

Comment: p.s. i am just a beginner, so need to understand how it works in terms of call stack of browser.

Comment: Please add the HTML code as well

Comment: I don't think your code actually works. You're trying to assign to `const setInt` which should throw a TypeError. Later on you call `clearTimeout()` but never pass an argument in it.

Comment: thats not how you call clearTimeout, it need an argument

Comment: also, are you sure clicking the button should create another timeout every time? what if someone presses it multiple times in a row?

Comment: Also you shouldn't call `clearTimeout` to clear an interval set with `setInterval`, you should use `clearInterval` instead. Although oddly it will work.

Comment: You can't change the value of a variable with type is `const`. So, you just need to change  `let setInt = null;` and replaced `clearTimeout()` with `clearInterval(setInt)`

Comment: @Thomas the two are technically the same. You can clear a timeout with `clearInterval` and vice versa.

Comment: @Thomas admittedly, it's not a terribly useful information. I'd still prefer to match intervals with `clearInterval` and timeouts with `clearTimeout`. However, in this case there are bigger errors with the code and this won't cause an issue.

Comment: @yunzen i solved the error, thank you.

Comment: @VLAZ i saw the error as fast as i posted the question. thanks for pointing out though

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski basically, i have an array of pictures that should be auto iterated and after the array is done, picture should come back to the 1st one and stay there. and if user clicks on another category, then auto iteration should stop and go to that category. which is what i am unable to do. so i just wanted to know how set interval works under the hood to be able to manipulate better.

Comment: @Thomas it did, but with an error and clearInterval happened multiple times because it was inside setInterval().